# Show/Deserialize JSON in string

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have the next JSON

```
[[["Hello","Hola",,,1]],,"es"]
```

How can i get only the first object, in this case "Hello"?

Comment: This isn't valid json. You have both a string and an integer in the same array. Does the type matter and do you know the type that's supposed to be at the first place?

Comment: Thats the output from next url : https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=es&tl=en&dt=t&q=Hola

Comment: I would suggest going to their new api: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate-translate-text-protocol that json is not valid and looks very unstable.

Comment: @Dispersia: JSON does not require that the types of items in an array all have the same type. If anything is wrong with the JSON, it's the presence of empty elements in the array. JavaScript initialization notation allows this, and creates an array with no entries at the given indices, but I'm not sure the actual JSON spec allows it. If you do `JSON.stringify([[["Hello","Hola",,,1]],,"es"])`, you get `"[[["Hello","Hola",null,null,1]],null,"es"]"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JSON.NET, for example, you can do this:

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>("[[[\"Hello\",\"Hola\",,,1]],,\"es\"]");
string value = (string)((JValue)jsonObject[0][0][0]).Value;
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: Okay it looks like this is valid json :) Good catch

Comment: @mybirthname it's still not valid, however jsonconvert creates an array of plain objects by doing this, so this could be volatile if the type changes (which the array is of different types, so who knows what else it may or may not return). But I upvote simply due to it answers the question to the best of our knowledge.